# Different vertical alignment in VStack

Tags: swiftui

My goal is make `Text("Headline")` at the same level of Image top and `Divider()` at same level of Image bottom without loosing space for content between them. I tried default alignment of VStack and HStack, `.frame` and `.alignmentGuide` but nothing didn't help me. I'm avoiding use `Spacer()` in VStack because it eats space and content in `Text("Add info")` is missing.

```
    HStack {
        Image("temp 1")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)

            
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
            Text("Headline")
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)

            Text("Subheadline")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            Text("Add info: This Divider should be on bottom of Vstack")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .fontWeight(.regular)

            Divider()
        }
    }
    .padding(16)
```

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQnrV.png)

Line 1 on pic is where `Text("Headline")` should be, and Line 2 is where `Divider()`

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your desired output? It’s not clear what you exactly want.

Comment: Can you please share an attachment of the desired output?

Comment: Added a picture, hope it seems more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested. Works perfectly:

```
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Image("fox")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120) // here
                .padding(.trailing, 4)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Headline")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                
                Spacer(minLength: 4)

                Text("Subheadline")
                   .font(.subheadline)
                   .foregroundColor(.secondary)

                Spacer(minLength: 4)

                Text("Add info: This Divider should be on bottom of Vstack")
                   .font(.subheadline)
                   .fontWeight(.regular)

                Spacer().frame(height: 4)
                
                Divider()
           }
           .frame(height: 120)
        }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, I think my picture a bit miss understanding, I don't wanna add rectangles at top and bottom, I wanna locate Views exact on this places

Comment: @Nizami try now

Comment: not a solution:
1. Adding .frame (width: metrics.size.width * 0.33) ruins the required image size and stretches it to full screen 
2. Divider not in the same level of image bottom (going out of the screen)

Comment: fixed. Did all that you want. All works well, screenshots attached.

Comment: I just removed Spacers between Text Views, and leave Spacer(minLength: 4) before Divider(). Perfect, Thx!